Girls camp movie
I saw a movie on network TV in the late 90s.  Just know my memory might not be totally accurate about it. 
I think it was a kids movie about an all girls summer camp and I think there is a scene where the teepees that some of the girls built were being burned down.  I also think they use in canoes in one part.  It looked like it was filmed in the 70s or early 80s.  I am not completely sure about all of the details.  Anyone have any guesses?

Anything else you remember?

In Addams Family Values (1993) Wednesday and Pugsley are sent to summer camp.  The summer camp holds some kind of native American themed event and from pictures online (I can't remember how events unfold personally) it appears that Wednesday ends up burning down the teepees.

Also there's a scene with some canoes:


Hmm.  I will look into this

I am pretty sure that isn't it.
